# Get attribute values as array from selection of elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following using jQuery:

```
var x = $('.boxes > input:checked');
```

From x I am trying to retrieve an array of id values and have been unable to work out how to do this.

Something like:

```
var y = x[id];
// y becomes an array like ['1', '2', '3'] assuming
// that x had 3 checkboxes with id's of 1, 2, 3 etc.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map):

```
var x = $('.boxes > input:checked');

var y = $.map(x, function (element){
  return element.id;
});
```

The `y` variable, will be an array containing the element ids.

Comment: Alternatively: `var y = x.map(function() { return this.id;}).get();`