# Get every element values from class selector

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get attribute values as array from selection of elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258676/get-attribute-values-as-array-from-selection-of-elements-using-jquery)

I am trying to get the id from the list of elements

I have

```
<div class='test' id='123'> </div>
<div class='test' id='1243'> </div>

<div class='test' id='1223'> </div>
<div class='test' id='1423'> </div>
<div class='test' id='1223'> </div>
<div class='test' id='1253'> </div>
```

I want to get id for every div

I have

```
var idarray=[];

var id= $('.test').attr('id'); //would only get the first 123 id.

idarray.push(id)
```

How to I get every id to the idarray in my case? Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, it is not valid  HTML.

Comment: un..my codes don't have the same id.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
var idarray = $('.test').map(function(){return this.id}).get();
```

Comment: You are missing `.get` though... `idarray` will be a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to create your array, like this:

```
var id = $('.test').map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();
```

Comment: See dystroy's answer for a more efficient way to use the `.map()` method.  There's no need to use jQuery inside the callback.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, anyway will leave my answer as that so to have different solutions of the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a simple each loop.

```
var idarray=[];
$('.test').each(function(){idarray.push(this.id);})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `.each` loop, like this:

```
var idarray = [];

$(".test").each(function() {
    idarray.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
ids = [];
$("div").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    ids.push($this.attr("id"));
});
```

This would result in an array of `id`s.

Comment: You can simplify this to `ids.push(this.id)`.

Comment: Yes, but this _may_ be more readable to the OP.

Comment: Ok, even if you want to use `.attr`, why do you create an extra (global!) variable `$this`? I prefer readability too, but that's no reason to introduce unnecessary code. At least make `$this` local.

Answer (score 1):

use the below  code to id in idarray

```
var idarray = [];
$.each($(".test"),function(index,value)
   {
idarray.push($(value).attr("id"));
   });
```

Check for the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/E8Rjs/5/
Thanks