# JQuery - How to save the Values of a Div with the same class within a Div into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save the Values of divs with same class inside an Array.

I tried it with `.html()` this worked for me. But I just need the value but `.val()` doesn't work.

My JQuery:

```
   var array = [$("#myLists").find('.list').val()]; //.val() does not work

    $.each(array, function( index, value ) {

          alert( index + ": " + value );

    });
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="myLists">
   <div id="list" class="list" value="value1"></div>
   <div id="list" class="list" value="value2"></div>
   <div id="list" class="list" value="value3"></div>
   <div id="list" class="list" value="value4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.val` only works on form control elements (input, select, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get attribute values as array from selection of elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258676/get-attribute-values-as-array-from-selection-of-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

1. [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to convert the dom elements to an array representation
2. [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to read the value of the attribute value
3. remove the . from `class=".list"` since the `.` is used to represent the class selector

So

```
<div id="myLists">
    <div id="list" class="list" value="value1"></div>
    <div id="list" class="list" value="value2"></div>
    <div id="list" class="list" value="value3"></div>
    <div id="list" class="list" value="value4"></div>
</div>
```

then

```
var array = $('#myLists .list').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('value')
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Y9vZ/)

Comment: @Arun can you pls explain what .get() is doing here?

Comment: @RakeshKumar `.map()` returns a jQuery object, [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) returns an array of objects from that jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

[.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
var array = $("#myLists .list").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('value')
}).get();
```

---

Correct your HTML

ID must be unique and remove `.` from class in HTML

```
<div id="myLists">
    <div class="list" value="value1"></div>
    <div class="list" value="value2"></div>
    <div class="list" value="value3"></div>
    <div class="list" value="value4"></div>
</div>
```

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/LcPyk/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is invalid because `id` is unique , it should be:

```
<div id="myLists">
   <div class="list" value="value1"></div>
   <div class="list" value="value2"></div>
   <div class="list" value="value3"></div>
   <div class="list" value="value4"></div>
</div>
```

then you can use:

```
var array = $('#myLists .list').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('value')
}).get(); //.val() does not work

$.each(array, function( index, value ) {

    alert( index + ": " + value );

});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WJzT/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var optionValues = [];
 $("#myListsli .list").each(function() { optionValues .push($(this).attr('value')) });
```

Using jquery `.get()`

```
 var optionValues = $("#myLists .list").map(function(){return $(this).attr('value')}).get();
```